# EA Addin - call Synchronize Structural Elements action

Tags: add-in, enterprise-architect

I developed an Addin for EA using C#. After I add a diagram using an API, the property flows are not visible on the diagram until I go to diagram manually right click -> Synchronize Structural Elements. Is there a way to do ***Synchronize Structural Elements*** from the .net code for that specific diagram?

[image]

Comment: I don't think so. You'll have to recreate the functionality I'm afraid.

Comment: Never seem that. Wouldn't a diagram refresh do the same?

Comment: @qwerty_so I don't think so. IIRC this function adds all embedded elements to the diagram, possibly even as instances depending in on the situation.